# Antd multiple select remove values that are not in options list anymore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have 2 selects, car brands and car models. List of models depends on which brands user selected.

When user removes a brand, I update the options list for models, however, selected values remain even if they are no longer in the options list.

Is it possible to remove them automatically ?

Comment: set the select value index back to 0 `select.selectedIndex = 0`

Comment: This is a react component, not a native select

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the value of the model to the first element of the new model array.

something like:

```
handleModelRemove = (value) => {
    // handle remove logic...
    this.setState({
      brand: selectedBrand,
      selectedModel: selectedBrand.models[0],
    });
  }

<Select value={this.state.selectedModel}>
          {modelOptions}
        </Select>
```

You will need to POST SOME CODE for better help.